# sorting collections

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have a list of Persons object having two attributes name and age. I want to sort this list by age in ascending order, the sorting should be such that all the persons whose names are same should be at the bottom of the list.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried?

Comment: Its hard to believe that you did _any_ research before asking this question.

Comment: i had written a PersonComparator class that implements the Comparator interface and overrides the compare(). Following is the source code:

Comment: public int compare(Person p1, Person p2)
 {
  int comparison = 0;
  switch(p)
  {
    case AGE_ASC:
    if(p1.getAge()== p2.getAge())
    {
     // Do i need to do something here.
    }
    else
    {
    comparison = p1.getAge() - p2.getAge();
    if(comparison!=0)
    return comparison;
    }
    break;
    case AGE_DESC:
    comparison = p2.getAge() - p1.getAge();
    if(comparison!=0)
    return comparison;
    break;
     
  }

Comment: I snuggest you filter out duplicates first, and store these in a separate list. Possible removing them from the original list. Once you did that, sort as suggested below. For finding duplicates, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6737212/how-to-find-duplicates-in-an-arraylistobject

Answer (score 2):

Implement `Compareable` interface in your `Person` class (I don't really follow your logic but I think you can change the `compareTo` method into something you need):

```
static class Person implements Comparable<Person> {
    final String name;
    final int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Person o) {
        if (o.age == age)
            return o.name.compareTo(name);
        return Integer.valueOf(age).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(o.age));
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    List<Person> persons = new LinkedList<Person>();
    persons.add(new Person("David", 29));
    persons.add(new Person("Linnéa", 27));
    persons.add(new Person("Andreas", 28));
    persons.add(new Person("Christofer", 29));

    Collections.sort(persons);

    for (Person p : persons)
        System.out.println(p.name + " " + p.age);
}
```

Output:

```
Linnéa 27
Andreas 28
David 29
Christofer 29
```

Comment: `all the persons whose names are same should be at the bottom of the list`

Comment: Doesn't make any sense.. I hope ritesh doesn't mean that :)

Comment: I meant Persons having the same name should not be sorted but should be added after all the objects which are sorted by age.

Comment: i am able to achieve what i want but i don't think that is a good idea. I have first sorted the list using the comparator i have written and after that, running a nested for loop to swap  the object which has same name using Collections.swap()

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Collections.sort](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List%29) in order to sort a list according to the natural ordering of its elements. All elements in the list (i.e. Person objects in your case) should implement the [Comparable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `Comparable` use `Comparator`. The `Comparator` interface gives you the capability to sort a given collection any number of different ways. The other handy thing about the `Comparator` interface is that you can use it to sort instances of any class—even
classes you can't modify—unlike the `Comparable` interface, which forces you to change the class whose instances you want to sort.

Comment: i have used Comparator but stuck in how to place those objects which have same name after the list is sorted by age in asc order.

Answer (score 0):

Ooh, my spider-sense is tingling and makes me suspect a homework assignment :) I'll merely give you the basic idea.

You could sort the list with a regular comparator and then group the names according to the name with another loop.
With lambdaJ I would do it like this:

```
List persons = new LinkedList(){{
        add(new Person("David", 29));
        add(new Person("Linnéa", 21));
        add(new Person("Linnéa", 27));
        add(new Person("Linnéa", 29));
        add(new Person("Andreas", 28));
        add(new Person("Christofer", 29));
        }};

List sorted = sort(persons, on(Person.class).getAge());
Group groups = group(sorted, by(on(Person.class).getName()));
        
    for(Person person: groups.findAll()){
        System.out.println(person);
    }
```

**Output:**

```
Linnéa: 21
Linnéa: 27
Linnéa: 29
Andreas: 28
David: 29
Christofer: 29
```

Comment: Thanks can you give some more details :)